# Jenkins: ruby command not found for build

Tags: ruby, git, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I tried build ruby application using jenkins

but, occuered error

```
/tmp/jenkins#############.sh: line : ruby: command not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
```

Make sure there is no ruby ​​in the jenkins server

```
$ ruby -v
ruby 2.5.1p57 (2018-03-29 revision 63029) [x86_64-linux]

$which ruby
~/.rbenv/shims/ruby
```

I searched some issue but my problem not fix

Since jenkins is installed from vps and not set from 0, I do not know the neighborhood well.

Put .bash_profile for reference

```
# .bash_profile

# Get the aliases and functions
if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
        . ~/.bashrc
fi

# User specific environment and startup programs

PATH=$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin

export PATH
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are exporting ruby path in the PATH variable, you need to source .bash_profile at the beginning of your jenkins job so that it will export the variables for that shell/job.

Thanks,
Piyush

Comment: Thanks comment 

so tell me about how to export shell/job 
I tried exprot jenkins shell but not sucess

thanks

Comment: add shell that command

```
export PATH="/var/lib/jenkins/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

resolved this issue

thanks

Comment: I am glad that it worked out for you, you can support my answer by an up vote if you think it was helpful!